# Does a using block guarantee that the object will not be disposed until the end of the block?

Tags: c#, idisposable, using

I know a `using` block ensures that the `IDisposable` object being "used" will be disposed at the end of the block - but does it **guarantee** that the object will not be disposed before then?

In other words, if I have:

```
using (new DisposableObject()) {
  // blah blah
}
```

can I be sure that the `DisposableObject` will not be disposed until the end of the block, or might the garbage collector detect that I have no handle to it inside the block, and dispose it right away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your object will only be disposed once and will not be GC'd before the end of the using block.

The specification guarantees that when you have `using (expression) statement` and the type of expression is a nullable type (call it `ResourceType`) then it is expanded into:

```
{
   ResourceType resource = expression;
   try {
      statement;
   }
   finally {
      if (resource != null) ((IDisposable)resource).Dispose();
   }
}
```

`Dispose` will be called once at the end of the block and there is a local generated that keeps a reference to your disposable object. The local prevents the object from being GC'd before the end of the using block.

Comment: +1 That's the clearest explanation given, and worthy of answer credit.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

No it doesn't. There's nothing stopping you from doing:

```
using(var myObject = new DisposableObject())
{
    myObject.Dispose();
}
```

What exactly will happen in this case depends on the semantics of `DisposableObject`. It may throw an exception, or it may be perfectly happy with `Dispose` being called twice.

It should be noted that object disposal and garbage collection are completely different concepts. Just because an object is disposed doesn't mean it will be garbage collected and just because an object has been garbage collected doesn't mean it will be disposed.

An object may be garbage collected once all references to the object are destroyed or are unreachable. That can't happen while the code is running inside the `using`-block, because the block itself has a reference to the object.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. The issue is if the GC will call the finalizer before the end of the using block.

Comment: +1 Thank you for making that distinction between garbage collection and object disposal, which was not clear in my mind before.  So to rephrase my question: in the code in my question, can I depend on the `DisposableObject` not being *disposed* before the end of the `using` block?

Comment: @Shaul No there's no way to guarantee that the variable `myObject` won't be disposed before the end of the using block. The object may be disposed after all references to it are unreachable, but while you're in the using block, that won't happen because you've got a reference to it right there.

Comment: But you are guaranteed that the CLR *won't* dispose it - only user code will possibly dispose it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you rather want to know about garbage collection rather than disposing.

The garbage collector will not collect the object inside the `using` block. Even if you specifically call the `Dispose` method, there is still an active reference to it, so it won't be collected.

The code generated for the `using` block ends with checking if the object can be disposed, so that usage will keep the object alive during the `using` block.