# When is a `using var` disposed? Is it out-of-scope as soon as possible or at the end of the block?

Tags: c#, scope, using, idisposable, using-statement

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration

> The lifetime of a `using` local will extend to the end of the scope in which it is declared. The `using` locals will then be disposed in the reverse order in which they are declared.

My question is: when is a `using` local considered out-of-scope?
Is it necessarily at the end of the block?
Is it necessarily right after its last use in the block?
Or is it implementation-defined, so that it could be either, or even anywhere in-between?

In other words:

```cs
{
  using var res = Res();
  res.DoStuff();
  somethingElse.DoWhatever();
  res.DoMoreStuff();
  // 100 more statements that have nothing to do with res
}
```

Is this always equivalent to this (1)?

```cs
{
  using (var res = Res()) {
    res.DoStuff();
    somethingElse.DoWhatever();
    res.DoMoreStuff();
    // 100 more statements that have nothing to do with res
  }
}
```

Or always to this (2)?

```cs
{
  using (var res = Res()) {
    res.DoStuff();
    somethingElse.DoWhatever();
    res.DoMoreStuff();
  }
  // 100 more statements that have nothing to do with res
}
```

Or is this an implementation detail?
Does the spec define this? What is such "scope" technically? If one of the above is always the case, is there a reason to prefer this behavior over the other? I'd assume (2) is better, but maybe I'm wrong.

I know it probably doesn't change much for high-level programming, but I'm curious.

---

Somewhat related: [Does a using block guarantee that the object will not be disposed until the end of the block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515822/does-a-using-block-guarantee-that-the-object-will-not-be-disposed-until-the-end)

Comment: The braces and indentation show the scope

Comment: Easiest way to tell - try referring to it. If it compiles then it's in scope. If it doesn't then it isn't.

Comment: I guess my question was a bit confusing. I know that the variable is still "in scope" at "edit-time". My question is more of whether the compiler may "optimize" and "terminate" its "run-time" scope early (causing it to dispose possibly before the end of the block) since I'm no longer referencing it. I'm asking because it *could* do that and the code would be "functionally equivalent" -- unless the spec actually mandates that this syntax means necessarily that the finally/dispose HAS to be added at the end of the scope/block.

Comment: This doubt always pops up in my mind when using this language feature, and I hate that it doesn't seem to be specified explicitly anywhere. Especially since the compiler/runtime is explicitly *not* guaranteed to keep local variables alive until the end of the declaring block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what a [Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#77-scopes) means according to the language spec:

> The scope of a name is the region of program text within which it is possible to refer to the entity declared by the name without qualification of the name.
>
> [...]
>
> The scope of a local variable declared in a local_variable_declaration (§12.6.2) is the *block* in which the declaration occurs.

Note that a `using` declaration is just the word `using` added to a local variable declaration. According to the using declaration proposal,

> The language will allow for `using` to be added to a local variable declaration.

Therefore, your `using` declaration is equivalent to

```
{
  using (var res = Res()) {
    res.DoStuff();
    somethingElse.DoWhatever();
    res.DoMoreStuff();
    // 100 more statements that have nothing to do with res
  }
}
```

The outermost `{ ... }` denotes a [Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#123-blocks).

Comment: OK, but does that *really* guarantee that the implicit Dispose added by the syntax will only be called after the 100 statements? I'm not convinced that the compiler won't possibly "optimize" it to (2), i.e. maybe call Dispose before the end of block but after I'm no longer referencing it (where it's functionally equivalent to being "out-of-scope"). Is there a guarantee in the actual spec for `using var` that the implicit try-finally really extends to the end of the entire block?

Comment: I said "actual spec" because I'm not sure if the pages linked in the question are the "definitive"/final spec... it's split by C# version weirdly and it has "proposal" in the URL, and they seem more like drafts. But I couldn't find anything else, so maybe they ARE the whole formal spec...?

Comment: @geekley there is no “actual spec”, only drafts at this moment. They are still writing the spec for C# 7, and this feature is in C# 8. Be patient and wait :) As for not moving the `Dispose` call before the end of the block, the wording in the proposal is as close to a guarantee as you can get right now. And this is not an optimisation. Changing from (1) to (2) changes the program behaviour completely. Think about what happens if an exception is thrown in `res.DoStuff();`.

Comment: Ah I see. So the spec is guaranteeing that if an exception is thrown, the 100 statements will not run. Thanks for clarifying that (1) and (2) are functionally different. That makes a lot of sense now!

Comment: No, wait. Now I'm confused. I really think (1) and (2) ARE functionally equivalent. If an exception is thrown, the same happens in both cases: 100 statements won't run either way (neither before nor after Dispose) because `using` doesn't imply a `catch`. The only difference would be that on successful execution, (2) calls Dispose earlier no? Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @geekley huh, I cannot remember what I was thinking that day… Anyway, the behaviour is different even if no exception is thrown, since `Dispose` is called at a different point in time. If it has some side effects (like changing a static field somewhere) for example, the 100 lines of code would observe that in (2) but not in (1).

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET Blog in [Do more with patterns in C# 8.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/#using-declarations) we can read:

> Using declarations are simply local variable declarations with a using keyword in front, and their contents are disposed at the end of the current statement block.

And then we can see:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using var options = Parse(args);
    if (options["verbose"]) { WriteLine("Logging..."); }

} // options disposed here
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, about

> The `using` locals will then be disposed in the reverse order in which they are declared.

```
using (var v1 = Class1()) // disposed third
using (var v2 = Class2()) // disposed second
using (var v3 = Class3()) // disposed first
{
  . . . .
}
```